# Help understanding code to build circuit for plant reader

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm working a design project that measures the tiny changes of conductivity in a plant. (To visualize how a plant reacts to its environment) I'm working with Arduino to realize that. Two wires are hooked up to the plant to measure the changes and are connected to the Arduino. I haven't worked with Arduino before but a friend got me the code from his plant reader (he got help too and doesn't know how to build it anymore). I do understand most of it but I just don't manage to translate the code he gave me into a circuit on the Arduino bread board. I use processing to visualize the measurements afterwards.
[image: Code plant reader]

Who can help me building the circuit. I don't get what's happening at pin13. Thank you for helping me :)

Comment: Please copy and paste the code into your question (edit the question to do this). That makes it much easier to read and comment on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pin13 is attached to the onboard LED.

So when you see a reference to it, it means that the program is turning the light ON/OFF. You do not need to do any wiring with it.

But the logic seems strange: it turns the LED off only when the analog reading is out of range (and it resets the stress).

It seems to imply that once the plant is stressed, it will stay stressed :-)

Btw, as side note: posting the code in ASCII form would allow people to quote/comment on it. The screenshot is not very good for that purpose.

What cannot be figured out from the code, is how to instrument your plant.
If your friend has a working setup, you could try to replicate it.
At least post a few pictures.